# How to make a graphical terminal in C under linux?

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm using `/bin/sh` to execute some commands, but some of those commands require me to have a "graphical terminal" which I don't really know what that means, those commands give wrong output on my software, but correct output on the normal `Gnome/KDE` Terminal.

I was wondering if there is away to tell the underlying `X Window Session` that my software is a "graphical terminal"?

Comment: Sorry but are we talking about X or simple curses terminal UI ? The application is an X app (relies on AtenaWidgets or Gtk) or simply outputs to terminal ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. Do you want to start a graphic terminal, or to check that your command has been started from a graphic environment???

Comment: its a simple C application, no dependencies, and it executes some commands from /bin to preform some operations, and thats all

Comment: When you run your "commands" how do you know they require a "graphical terminal"? what do they say? how are you running them? what are they?  This might mean you need X or it might want a particular terminal type.

Answer (score 1):

As @ugoren said, the `DISPLAY` variable is what is used to find the X Window System from applications. If X is not running in the background, the variable will be unset.

You can start a new X server using `xinit` from your script if you cannot talk to the old one; ideally, this would be something like Xvnc (which does not need hardware access).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to run application on a remote machine or at least one that doesn't run any [X Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). If that is the case you might try to use [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) which creates a virtual server which allows applications to connect to it and "draw" windows.

Comment: If on a remote machine, you could connect to it using `ssh -X` (which, when suitably configured, is forwarding X11).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, software that uses X windows relies on the `DISPLAY` environment variable.
It's value should be something like `10.0.0.1:0.0`, where 10.0.0.1 is your IP address (I'm not sure what `0.0` is, but `0.0` normally works).
You also need some X server software to run on your PC, which would show the window.

Comment: Inventing a value for the `DISPLAY` variable is almost always a bad idea, especially if you don't understand how it's formed.

Comment: @SimonRichter the worst that can happen is that the program exits when it fails to connect to the invalid address.

Comment: It could also connect to a different session, e.g. if I am logged in at home (`:0.0`) and via ssh (`:10.0`).